# Why isn't this short circuit is not working in linq to sql query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

The query:

```
List<int> companyIds = null;

(from car in context.GetTable<Car>()
where companyIds == null || companyIds.Contains(car.companyID)
select car)
.ToList();
```

The result:

> at System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType[TResult](IEnumerable source)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitContains(Expression sequence, Expression value)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression predicate)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(Expression node)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
>      at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at EVaultSDK.Services.CompanyService.Get...

If I add ToList

```
 context.GetTable<Car>().ToList()
```

It works

Comment: Is the question mark operator applicable here?

Comment: @maccettura Not sure I agree with that, the code presented above is logically correct, though it's missing a `select` so I'm not sure it's complete.

Comment: @maccettura,read about short circuit,if the first clause is true,no need to perform the second clause

Comment: @cosset so you want every record where companyIds is null, and where the companyIds contains x?

Comment: @DavidG,you are right,added the select

Comment: @maccettura,I want if companyIds is null - return all cars,if not - return only cars that have appropriate companyId.Of course I made companyIds = null before the query only for example

Comment: Context is not null,companyIds is null and linq try to execute contains on null,but it shouldn't execute the second clause as the first is true

Comment: @cosset can you try adding `ToList` here: `context.GetTable<Car>().ToList()` and see if you get the exception again. And can you post the full Stack trace of the exception ?

Comment: yep, stack trace confirms my suspicion.

Comment: @CetinBasoz,yes,your answer can be called solution,but it's logically incorrect,if I pass to method empty(not null) companyIds,I expect the method return nothing,for  that puprpose companyIds can be nullable,

Comment: @cosset, OK I will edit my solution just for you.

Comment: If you add context.GetTable<Car>().ToList() it doesn't really work. In that case you are beating your purpose and bringing in all the data regardless of what you have in your selections. With small data it would go unnoticeable but if you have large data beware you are pulling down the wire the whole table every time.

Comment: @CetinBasoz,yes,I know about it

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason is you are using LINQ to SQL, your query needs to be translated into SQL and you get the exception while this translation happens. The `Contains` is translated into `IN` operator in SQL. But since the list is null I think the LINQ to SQL provider throws an exception.

This is the reason why you don't get the exception when you add `ToList` after `GetTable<Car>()`, this causes you to fetch and load all `Cars` in memory, therefore the query runs on memory so don't need to be translated to SQL and the short-circuiting works as expected.

Normally if you call `Contains` on a null list, you should get `NullReferenceException` but you are getting `ArgumentNullException`. So you should check stack trace and if it's the case, don't use a null list in your query.

Edit: The stack trace you posted confirms my assumption. Somewhere along the road `OfType` method is called on the list and it causes the exception.

Answer (score 2):

You already got a good answer on why you're getting the error - not everything in C# translates nicely to SQL, and you often don't find out until runtime.

Just in case a future visitor hits this question looking for a workaround,
I'd suggest using the fact that you can build a query up and it won't retrieve any data until you call `ToList()` (or `Single()`, etc...):

```
List<int> companyIds = null;

var query = context.GetTable<Car>();
if (companyIds != null)
    query = query.Where(car => companyIds.Contains(car.companyID));

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Hey be prepared to be down voted for providing a solution instead of an answer to his question:) BTW you miss AsQueryable().