# An exception occurred with using LINQ method syntax (LINQ to SQL) in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-sql, linq-method-syntax

I use Linq to Sql and method syntax of Linq in my code to query from database with all tables. And I met an weird exception today, this is the first time error occurred since I started to use L2S.

There are two columns in database table.
And the column of "Status" is mapping to program with an enumeration type: 1(Free), 2(Loan).

。Database table schema as below.
[image]

。Define table class

```
private string Type;
private byte Status;
```

。Query code

```
string _qNote = string.Empty;
string _qStatus = string.Empty;
List<DefineTableClass> _List = _dbObj.Table.Select(_obj => _obj)
                            .Where(_obj => 
                            (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_qNote) || _obj.Note == _qNote)
                            && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_qStatus) || Convert.ToInt32(_obj.Status) == Convert.ToInt32(_qStatus))
                            ).ToList();
```

The exception occurred at

> Convert.ToInt32(_obj.Status) == Convert.ToInt32(_qStatus)

and I am wondering this line should be passed at

> (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_qStatus)

due to **_qStatus** is **Empty** and it should not to do the next check.

Comment: The most likely cause is that the `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is not a function that Linq to SQL supports.  Try `string == "" || string == null`

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(_obj.Status)` may not be supported either.  What you could do is try materializing the result of the Linq to SQL query to a list by calling ToList() and then apply your Select to the resulting list; Linq to Objects supports all of the methods you're trying to call.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am sure Linq to SQL supports these two functions. Because I have other queries are also using this way to query from database, and it worked.

Comment: Then edit your question to include the *differences* between the queries that work and the queries that don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Improve your query by preparing parameters outside Queryable lambda:

```cs
string _qNote = string.Empty;
string _qStatus = string.Empty;

var query = _dbObj.Table.AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_qNote))
    query = query.Where(_obj => _obj.Note == _qNote);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_qStatus))
{
    var byteStatus = Convert.ToByte(_qStatus);
    query = query.Where(_obj => _obj.Status == byteStatus);
}

var _List = query.ToList();
```

It should produce more effective SQL and may avoid unwanted conversions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the similar situations with my question.

L2S will check **ALL** where conditions, so it must to do `(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_qStatus)` no matter the front check we think it's should be passed cause it's true.

The better way to write L2S might less use casting in the syntax and like @SvyatoslavDanyliv said, preparing parameters outside Queryable lambda can prevent the weird logic question as mine at this time.

Reference:

[Why isn't this short circuit is not working in linq to sql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335811/why-isnt-this-short-circuit-is-not-working-in-linq-to-sql-query)

[Why isn't this short circuit in lambda working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079556/why-isnt-this-short-circuit-in-lambda-working)